# $\Lambda$ has infinite repetition index, rep$(\Lambda /J)=\infty$, why?

Tags: rt.representation-theory

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1407.2321v1.pdf $P_{6}$, Example 2.3(c) If $\Lambda=K[X^{2}, Y^{2}]/(X^{2}, Y^{2})$ for a field,
then $\Lambda$ has infinite repetition index and, a fortiori, infinite syzygy type; in fact,  rep$(\Lambda /J)=\infty$.  rep$(\Lambda /J)=\infty$, why?

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1407.2321v1.pdf

Answer (score 3):

You surely mean $A=K[x,y]/(x^2,y^2)$.
This is a selfinjective algebra and thus $\Omega^1$ is an equivalence of the stable module category. Note that $A/J$ is just the unique simple module $S$. The simple module $S$ is not periodic in this algebra as is easily verified and thus $\Omega^i(S)$ are all indecomposable non-isomorphic. 
This shows all claims.

Comment: How to verify that $\Omega^{i}(S)$ are all indecomppsable non-isomorphic ?

Comment: @JunlingZheng That it is indecomposable follows since $\Omega^1$ is an equivalence of the stable category and that they are non-isomorphic follows then since the vector space dimension of $\Omega^i(S)$ is equal to $2i+1$ as one can easily verify.